# Horizontal Scroller, change functionality from pixels to percentages

Tags: javascript, css, responsive-design

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lq2o5wav/6/

Disclaimer: On a scale of 1 to 10, I am a 2, maybe a 3 on my JS abilities. I can sort of read it but can't manipulate it much. So…

I have a horizontal scrolling area that can also be advanced with a click. The functionality of it is all good, so no problems there. My issue is that when I try to change the layout to be responsive and use percentages instead of pixels, it stops working, because I am assuming it's the pixel overflow that triggers the functionality. I believe the cause lies somewhere in here (where the *px* is, which also appears in a 2-3 other places in the JS):

```
if (availableScrollLeft < SETTINGS.navBarTravelDistance * 2) {
    pnProductNavContents.style.transform = "translateX(" + availableScrollLeft + "px)";
}
```

The way the fiddle is set up now, if you change line 66 in the CSS to a percentage value instead of pixels, the advancing arrows disappear because they are triggered by "determineOverflow" and "data-overflowing" which are reacting to pixel values not % values.

So I would love to keep all the functionality but be able to make this responsive — both the container and the boxes within it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How do you want the ```.pn-ProductNav_Link``` to behave in order to be "responsive"? If you take the width off of the ```nav``` the whole thing will adjust to the size of its parent.

Comment: The various `.pn-ProductNav_Link` boxes should change width relative to the width of `nav` so ideally they are always, say, 25% the width of `nav`. Right now, they are always 240px wide regardless of whether `nav` is 1,000px wide or 2,000px wide, so depending on the width of the browser you see more boxes or less boxes as `nav` expands and contracts; I want to always see, say, 4 boxes that expand and contract with the layout.

Answer (score 0):

It's a good idea to put the duty of sizing on one element if possible. In this case the parent of `nav` determines the size of `nav`. Then use flex for its wonderful abilities to fill the available space with its children.

Apply to what you have with this...

```
nav {
  ...
  width: auto; // or just remove the existing width rule.
  display: flex;
  ...
}

.pn-ProductNav_Link {
  ...
  flex: 1;
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea… unless I tested it wrong, it doesn't solve the issue since there is still a loss of the "px" value — when switching from width x to flex — that triggers the JS to work.

Comment: I would eliminate determining the width explicitly. Flex will do the work for you.

Comment: You can add ```min-width``` to make sure it stays wide enough. I made a pen: https://codepen.io/bstees/pen/gObLxeW